# SAS Proc GLM and Npar1way

Tags: sas, proc

1.(a) Examine the significance of the differences between the mean worms counts for the four control groups using ANOVA test. Alpha=0.05

(b) If part (a) is significant, find pairs of groups that are significantly different in mean worms counts. Alpha=0.05

2. (a) Examine the significance of the differences between the means for the four control groups using

Kruskal-Wallis test (Nonparametric Test). Alpha=0.05

(b) Rank your response (all worms counts) in ascending order (choose “mean" tie) and save the ranks

in a dataset "rankworms".

(c) Examine the significance of the differences between the mean ranks of the four control groups using

ANOVA test. Compare your result with Kruskal Wallis test. Use “rankworms" dataset Alpha=0.05`enter code here`

My Code

```
data why;
input group $ worm @@;
datalines;
1 279 2 378 3 172 4 381
1 238 2 275 3 335 4 346
1 234 2 412 3 335 4 340
1 198 2 265 3 282 4 471
1 303 2 286 3 250 4 318
;
*Part 1A*;
Proc GLM data=why Alpha=0.05;
Class group;
Model worm = group;
Means group;
Run;
Quit;
*Part 2A*;
Proc Npar1way data=why Alpha=0.05 Wilcoxon;
Class group;
Var worm;
Run;
Quit;
*Part 2B*;
Proc Rank data=why Ties=Mean out=rankworms;
By worm;
Ranks newworm;
Var worm;
Run; Quit;
*Part 2C*;
Proc Npar1way data=why Alpha=0.05 Anova;
Class group;
Var worm;
Run;Quit;
```

For part 2B I keep getting the error code "data may be incomplete". I tried using proc sort in order to use a BY statement, however I kept getting that the data was not sorted in ascending order. I was under the perception that whenever you used Proc sort it automatically sorted everything by ascending order. For everything else I would just like to make sure that I am on the right track the questions are kinda confusing to me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from 2B.

```
BY WORM ;
```

since you don't want each worm to be ranked, but the groups of worm. It should probably be

```
BY GROUP;
```

You'll probably need to sort it by groups first as well.